# Concisely renaming/ replacing subsets of a key in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a biological data set where "species" is the key for the data.table, but some of the species names are wrong / actually refer to the same species, and thus need to be grouped and renamed.

As a smaller, simpler example, below I use letters of the alphabet, which I want to group and rename accordingly as vowels, consonants, or both (y).

I can achieve the goal, but my specific question is this: Is there a way to refer to multiple sets of the key in `i`, and then use `:=` to group+rename the key? I.e., I want to do the renaming in one step, not 3.

```
test <- data.table(type=letters, letnum=seq_along(letters), key="type") # starting data.table
print(test) # print starting data.table

test[c("a","e","i","o","u"),type:="vowel"] # replace vowels
setkey(test, type) # need to reset key (I can't figure out to do it in the previous line)

test[c("y"), type:="both"] # replace the special case, y
setkey(test, type)

test[!c("vowel","both"), type:="consonant"] # repalce the consonants
setkey(test, type)

print(test) # print the final data.table
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of the changes you want, and then you can do it all in one step:

```
dict = data.table(old.type = letters, new.type = "consonant", key = 'old.type')
dict[c("a","e","i","o","u"), new.type := "vowel"]['y', new.type := 'both']

setkey(test, type)

test[dict, type := new.type]
```

Another alternative is creating a new column instead of overwriting and then having to reset the key every time.